# Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I am getting below error in my laravel 5.6 project.

```
"message": "Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError
```

I have checked my AWS ami server.All the modules like SimpleXMLElement and phpxml installed .But i am getting this error.

Comment: Show the code that triggers the error.

Comment: $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($arrData ,  0, true);

Comment: Do you have the DOM extension installed? (if not, you should be able to with something similar to : ```sudo apt install php7.3-xml```)

Comment: it is already installed in my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution :

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```